# Unity - Resolve by configuration without reference to the type

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, unity-container

I want to Resolve a type without having a reference to the project where the type exist.
I want that the Resolve  will load the correct assembly in runtime.

The issue is = that in runtime I decide which type to use... and according to that I want to load the correct assembly.

How can I do it?

thanks

Comment: You can do it via Reflection, but it is slow and error-prone.

Comment: Sure, I don't want to use reflection... thats why i'm using unity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you expect Unity to do? Vodoo?

You can either configure Unity using app/web.config and just drop the required assemblies in your app base folder. But that is configuration at design time.

Or you use code to configure the container which either lets you use `Assembly.Load` to get access to all assemblies that are not directly referenced by your app domain. Then you would have to use reflection of some kind to extract the types that will be dynamically registered.

Or you can skip the "let's be even more dynamic" approach and reference all neccessary assemblies in some kind of bootstrapper.

The third alternative would be to modularize your code configuration and use conventions to register those modules at runtime. Unity does not support this third approach out-of-the-box but there is a port of the StructureMap config engine available in the [TecX project](http://tecx.codeplex.com). See the documentation or the code in the *TecX.Unity.Configuration* project. Tests are available to demonstrate how it works.

Comment: Can it do Vodoo it will be great :) I hoped that it has register for assembly. I will check TecX project... thanks

Comment: @Guy Sorry but magic is not part of p&p's daily business. If my answer was helpful otherwise it would be great if you could mark it as such. Thanks